# Polymorphism without implementing all virtual methods

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

Is NOT implementing a virtual method in all derived classes considered a bad programming practice when using polymorphism?

Let's say I have an Enemy class and a couple of derived classes. All of the enemy types have an Attack() method, but only some of them are able to jump. In this case all enemies except orcs have a jumping skill.

```
using System;

namespace Polymorphism
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Enemy enemy1 = new Spider();
            Enemy enemy2 = new Goblin();
            Enemy enemy3 = new Orc();
        }
    }

    abstract class Enemy
    {   
        //I'm making this abstract because all derived classes will implement this anyway
        public abstract void Attack();

        //This is virtual because not all derived enemy types can jump
        public virtual void Jump()
        {
            //nothing here
        }
    }
   

    class Spider : Enemy
    {
        public override void Attack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bite attack!");
        }

        public override void Jump()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Spider jump animation");
        }
    }

    class Goblin : Enemy
    {
        public override void Attack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arrow attack!");
        }

        public override void Jump()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goblin jump animation");
        }
    }

    class Orc : Enemy
    {
        public override void Attack()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Axe attack!");
        }

        //no jump method here! 
    }
}
```

Even though orcs can't jump, the base class's Jump() method is still available to call, even though it does absolutely nothing in the case of orcs. I find Intellisense still "recommending" the jump button a bit misleading, and it doesn't seem like a good programming habit to me either. Is this a bad approach and what are the alternatives, if I really want to be able to, say, put all of my enemy objects in the same array? As far as I know, you can't really access non-overridden methods in derived classes, and casting sounds like a hassle.

Comment: "you can't really access non-overridden methods in derived classes" - since when? To your question, though, I'd be tempted to consider either having a virtual get-only property `CanJump` or else defining (and implementing where appropriate) an `IJumper` interface.

Comment: Have you considered `ISupportsJump` (which `Kangaroo` would implement, but not `Orc`)? Then if you have an `Enemy` instance - `(enemy as ISupportsJump)?.Jump();`

Comment: I don't think Intellisense is that smart to know when you need to add a missing action like this. I would not listen to it here.

Answer (score 1):

you can reach any method in base class except private. Try this

```
abstract class BaseEnemy
{
    //I'm making this abstract because all derived classes will implement this anyway
    public abstract void Attack();
    
}

abstract class AdvancedEnemy:BaseEnemy
{
    
    //This is virtual because not all derived enemy types can jump
    public virtual void Jump()
    {

    }

}


class Spider : AdvancedEnemy
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bite attack!");
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Spider jump animation");
    }
}

class Goblin :  AdvancedEnemy
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrow attack!");
    }

    public override void Jump()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Goblin jump animation");
    }
}

class Orc : BaseEnemy
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Axe attack!");
    }

    

    //no jump method here! 
}
```